# DUALSTACK_ENDPOINT_ENABLED while s3Client builder

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

While creating the s3Client object through Java SDK 2.0. Trying to build s3 client object in spring boot program. Please let me know if you can help out to fix this.

```
package com.dnd.adx.lambda.keymgmnt.config;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.DefaultCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3ClientBuilder;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.SnsClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.SnsClientBuilder;

@Component
public class GatewayKeyManagementConfig {

    private ProcessBuilder processBuilder;
    private SnsClient snsClient;
    private S3Client s3Client;
    private AwsCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider;
    private String region;

    public GatewayKeyManagementConfig() {
        this.awsCredentialsProvider = DefaultCredentialsProvider.builder().build();
    }

    public void setRegion(String region) {
        this.region = region;
    }

    // ProcessBuilder configuration.
    public synchronized ProcessBuilder getProcessBuilder() {
        if (processBuilder == null) {
            processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        }
        return processBuilder;
    }

    // Sns client configuration.
    public synchronized SnsClient getSnsClient() {
        if (snsClient == null) {
            SnsClientBuilder builder = SnsClient.builder();
//          SnsClientBuilder credentialsProvider = builder.credentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider);
            SnsClientBuilder region2 = builder.region(Region.of(region));
            snsClient = region2.build();
        }

        return snsClient;
    }

    // S3 client configuration.
    public synchronized S3Client getS3Client() {
        if (s3Client == null) {
            S3ClientBuilder builder = S3Client.builder();
            builder = builder.region(Region.of(region));
            s3Client = builder.build();
        }
        return s3Client;
    }
}
```

Getting exception while building the s3Client object at **s3Client = builder.build();**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DUALSTACK_ENDPOINT_ENABLED
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3BaseClientBuilder.finalizeServiceConfiguration(DefaultS3BaseClientBuilder.java:112)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.builder.AwsDefaultClientBuilder.finalizeChildConfiguration(AwsDefaultClientBuilder.java:132)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder.syncClientConfiguration(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:183)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3ClientBuilder.buildClient(DefaultS3ClientBuilder.java:36)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3ClientBuilder.buildClient(DefaultS3ClientBuilder.java:25)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder.build(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:150)
    at com.dnd.adx.lambda.keymgmnt.config.GatewayKeyManagementConfig.getS3Client(GatewayKeyManagementConfig.java:55)
    at com.dnd.adx.lambda.keymgmnt.service.impl.FileOperationServiceImpl.uploadFile(FileOperationServiceImpl.java:148)
    at com.dnd.adx.lambda.keymgmnt.service.impl.CommonServiceImpl.generateKeysReport(CommonServiceImpl.java:215)
    at com.dnd.adx.lambda.keymgmnt.function.GenerateKeysReportFunction.apply(GenerateKeysReportFunction.java:29)
    at com.dnd.adx.lambda.keymgmnt.GatewayKeyManagementApplication.main(GatewayKeyManagementApplication.java:26)
```

The same piece of code is working in another project but throwing **DUALSTACK_ENDPOINT_ENABLED**